# where does Apple's iOS AVCAM sample app put the output files?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, video-capture, avcam

I downloaded AVCAM, ran it, recorded a video and made a still.
Did it store the video and still in a file somewhere?
Or is the sample just an example of creating av assets, and I must process the assets?

Ultimately, I want to compress and transmit the capture video&audio to a remote server by HTTP LIVE STREAMING.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code to the sample, it uses `-writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:orientation:completionBlock:` to write still images to your device's photo library.

Videos are first recorded to `output.mov` in the application's temporary files directory and then either written to the application's documents directory (if only recording audio) or moved to the photo library using `-writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL:completionBlock:`.